# Alternative Derivative Definition? $f'(x)=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\frac{\Delta x}{2})-f(x-\frac{\Delta x}{2})}{\Delta x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In a book about Numerical Methods I once saw the derivative defined as $$f'(x)=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\frac{\Delta x}{2})-f(x-\frac{\Delta x}{2})}{\Delta x}$$
I'm not sure if it always works though.

Suppose $f(x)=|x|$ and you want to find the derivative at $x=0$.  $f(x)=f(-x)$, so the numerator is $0$ regardless of your choice of $\Delta x$, so whether you approach from the left or the right, you get the same result, $0$. But $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

So that's one problem, and I'm not sure what's going on. This has me wondering, are there other points of failure?

Comment: If the usual derivative exists, then the [symmetric derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative) exists. You've provided a counterexample for the converse. Presumably the numerical methods you're studying are used in a situation where you know that the usual derivative exists, in which case you can approximate using the symmetric difference quotient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Converting my comment to an answer]

If the usual derivative exists, then the [symmetric derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative) exists. You've provided a counterexample for the converse. Presumably the numerical methods you're studying are used in a situation where you know that the usual derivative exists, in which case you can approximate using the symmetric difference quotient.